# How different is React’s ES6 syntax when compared to ES5?

Tags: reactjs

As I have declared variables and also successfully imported the required packages.
And then passed props, also the required function but can't able get the value in state. How should I get the value in state.
Want a proper guide by an example.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=es5+vs+es6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Some Key Differences

### Importing React

#### ES5

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;
```

#### ES6

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
```

### Creating React Component and Exporting it

#### ES5

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <header>
                <h1>This is the header section</h1>
            </header>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Header;
```

#### ES6

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <h1>This is the header section</h1>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

### PropTypes

#### ES5

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;

var Header = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
      title: ReactPropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
});
```

#### ES6

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <h1>This is the header section</h1>
            </header>
        );
    }
}

//Note that the propTypes has to be defined outside of the class definition

Header.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

The ES6 syntax looks weird because the propTypes section is outside of the class definition. This is due to the fact that only methods can be defined inside a class in ES6. If you want to define properties, they have to be outside of the class.

To avoid this issue, use ES7 Property Initialiazers:

#### ES7

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';

export default class Header extends Component {

    // brings the propTypes inside the class definition

    // Note that propTypes belongs to the class, and thus it is static

    // non-static properties (instance properties) is shown in the next section

    static propTypes = {
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <h1>This is the header section</h1>
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

### getInitialState

#### ES5

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            title: this.props.title
        };
    },
});
```

#### ES6

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {    
/* Note props is passed into the constructor in order to be used */
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: props.title
        };
    }
}
```

To furthur simplify this code using ES7's property initializer:

#### ES7

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    // instance property

    state = {
        title: this.props.title
    };

    // followed by constructor...

}
```

### Invoking Methods

### ES5

```
var Header = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(event) {
        this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});  
    // Note here that **this** is automatically bind to the component itself
    }
});
```

However in ES6, the React team decided to not automatically bind this to the component. So to rewrite the code above in ES6, we need to bind the handleClick function to the component inside the constructor:

#### ES6

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    constructor() { 
        super();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});  
    }
}
```

The React blog suggests ES7 property initializers:

#### ES7

```
export default class Header extends Component {
    handleClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({liked: !this.state.liked});  
    }
}
```

handleClick = ... is ES7 property initializer syntax.
(event) => {} is ES6 fat arrow syntax which preserves context when it is called.

Comment: You dont have to define propTypes outside, you can use static.

Comment: I am not a react expert, please feel free to edit my answer